# Can't get sub query to work

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have 2 queries that work fine by themselves but I've been struggling to get them to work together.  I have a table of audits and I am trying to count the audits by auditor. I am using a form to get the date range and the auditor. The auditors are in a table named tblUser.  The main table is tblParatransitPullOutAudit. There is a field in this table named AuditId which tells me what Audit each record belongs to. There may be many records with the same Audit ID, these count as 1 audit. I want to count how many audits by date range and Auditor. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT 
    t.Contractor, 
    Count(t.PK_ParapullOut) AS Audits
FROM 
    tblUser 
    INNER JOIN 
    tblParatransitPullOutAudit AS t 
        ON tblUser.PK_User = t.Auditor
WHERE ((t.AuditDate) Between forms!frmTotalAuditsDateRangeAuditor!txbStartDate.value And forms!frmTotalAuditsDateRangeAuditor!txbEndDate.value) 
    And ((tblUser.PK_User)=Forms!frmTotalAuditsDateRangeAuditor!cboAuditor.value)
GROUP BY Contractor;


SELECT 
    p.Contractor, 
    Count(p.AuditID) AS Audits
FROM 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            p.Auditor, 
            p.AuditDate, 
            p.contractor, 
            p.auditid 
        FROM tblParatransitPullOutAudit AS p
    )  AS Total
WHERE ((p.AuditDate) Between forms!frmTotalAuditsDateRange!txbStartDate.value And forms!frmTotalAuditsDateRange!txbEndDate.value)
GROUP BY p.Contractor;
```

Comment: How they are not working?. What do you mean by `together`?. A trigger or stored procedure/function?. Also a `show create table` might help.

Comment: The first query counts all of the records by auditor and between the dates selected, but I only want to count the records that have a unique AuditId. The second query will count only the records with a unique AuditId, but because I'm using a form to get the Auditor's Name I have to lookup the Auditor in the usertable I can't seem to make this join work with the count distinct.

Comment: How can I attach tables to show you what I am trying to acomplish?

Comment: If ms-access has a command line with formatted output, post us enough of data rows from the tables to demonstrate the problem and your results which do not match your expectations. But right now, it's too much guessing on our part.